# fixed line or divider according to its content using html/css

Tags: html, css

How to set a line or divider height (not css line-height) according to the left or right section. For example, suppose we have a left panel and a right panel. We draw a line or divider on left side panel, line or divider grow according to the left panel content. But i want to grow this line or divider equal to the content of the panel, no matter which panel has more or less data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you take the normal div structure approach, its very complicated to get equal height divs unless, you are giving a fixed height using CSS. 
To achieve this goal, you can make your `div` structure to render as `table` layout, as height of columns depends upon the individual column with max-height.

Check this shared code, i have created a div structure and making it act like tables and given border to `.right` div, so if no matter, which column has how much data, the max-height column will be applicable to both

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* browser reset */
}
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.my-table {
  display: table;
  /* make it behave like table */
  table-layout: fixed;
  /* so that width of columns doesn't change as per content  */
}
.child {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
}
.my-col {
  display: table-cell;
  /* make it behave like table-cell */
}
/* just for visual example */

.my-col+.my-col {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent my-table">
  <div class="child my-col">No text with me...</div>
  <div class="child my-col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</div>
  <div class="child my-col">Home</div>
  <div class="child my-col">About.</div>
  <div class="child my-col">Contact</div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Kyll hope, it works! can't explain more than that..

Comment: Thanks for your answer.